# Echo username if column contains a specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I hope some one can help me.
I created a database with 11 different columns.
Now 1 column contains the username, for example John Doe.
On other column contains the place where John is stationed.
What I'd like to do is echo all the usernames that have the same location.

My code looks like this now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM zraInformatie";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<li><a href="vind-uw-reisadviseur/Noord-Holland/"' . $user . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

I picked the base of of an other thread but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.
The database is already connected to in the header part of the website.

Comment: If $row['location'] =='something'{ }

Comment: We need a little more information for this, but if you want usernames with the same location, in the mysql query you can do something like:

"SELECT * FROM zraInformatie WHERE location=something"

or are you using lat,lng?

Comment: Try altering your query to SELECT user FROM tablename WHERE location="mylocation"

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it all but I'm constantly getting the following error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in \header.php on line 101

Answer (score 0):

You need to selected a place where you want to see user name.

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM zraInformatie WHERE location=your selected place";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach($row as $field) {
  echo '<li><a href="vind-uw-reisadviseur/Noord-Holland/"' . $user .'</a</li>';
 }
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```